# form-inline form-group doesn't work

Tags: forms

In the html below I can't get inputs in one row, despite using "form-inline" and label class="sr-only". I tried many different things, no sucess

```
  <form class="form-inline">
 <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="hostname">Firewall hostname</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="hostname" class="form-control input-lg" id="hostname"
                   placeholder="Firewall">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="subnet">Firewall subnet</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="subnet" class="form-control input-lg" id="subnet">
        </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: lol my style.css is empty right now. I use bootstrap

Comment: hm..I think I had bootstrap.min.js instead of css in my html..You helped me to fix it, I can accept you answer if you want

Comment: If I really helped You it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Your HTML code contains only empty classes.
write in Your css file:

```
.form-inline{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and should be good :)

classes (and id's) do something ONLY if You previously declared their behaviour.